# Edit SVG diagram which was exported from RubyMine

Tags: database, svg, rubymine

I have a rails project and i exported database diagram using RubyMine (svg format). How i can edit this diagram (svg)? What linux program can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try svg-edit from google: http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

Also: http://ian.umces.edu/diagrammer/editor/svg-editor.html

and: http://inkscape.org/